# How do I change this particular string into a certain input

Tags: python, string, sorting, integer

I have the following line in my python program

```
print "Player 1: " +str(player1points)
```

where 'player1points' is calculate in my program.

The results yield:

```
Player 1: 3
```

where the '3' was what the program calculated for that run.

However for one particular function I managed to get help from here

```
def sort_players(players):
r"""Sort the players by points.

>>> print sort_players('Player 1: 3\n'
...                    '\n'
...                    'Player 2: 4\n'
...                    '\n'
...                    'Player 3: 3\n'
...                    '\n'
...                    'Player 4: 5\n')
Player 4: 5
Player 2: 4
Player 1: 3
Player 3: 3
"""
# split into a list
players = players.split("\n")

# filter out empty lines
players = [player for player in players if player != '']

def points(player_report):
    """Parse the number of points won by a player from a player report.

    A "player report" is a string like 'Player 2: 6'.
    """
    import re
    # Match the last string of digits in the passed report
    points = re.search(r'\d+$', player_report).group()
    return int(points)

# Pass `points` as a "key function".
# The list will be sorted based on the values it returns.
players.sort(key=points, reverse=True)

# Make the sorted list back into a string.
return "\n".join(players)
```

The function will only accept an input:

```
Player 1: 3
```

and not:

```
"Player 1: " +str(player1points)
```

Even though it appears to me that they both yield the same result, how will I be able to to convert

```
"Player 1: " +str(player1points)
```

into the appropriate input so the function will accept it.

Examples:

```
sort_players('Player 1: 3\n'
             '\n'
             'Player 2: 4\n'
             '\n'
             'Player 3: 3\n')
```

Will give me

```
Player 2: 4
Player 1: 3
Player 3: 3
```

Example 2:

```
sort_payers('Player 1: +str(player1points)\n'
            '\n'
            'Player 2: +str(player2points)\n'
            '\n'
            'Player 3: +str(player3points)\n')
```

Will give me

```
AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: I doubt this is the issue. Show some complete example that fails (and include the complete traceback and error message!) and one that works.

Comment: I guess you're on the wrong track while debugging your code. Please provide more details what's really happening, what error do you get, ... The use of split and the regex look wrong to me, but would need more details to explain it.

Comment: Vote to close: not a real question. Please re=phrase the question of post all the code. Also, if this is homework it should be marked as such.

Answer (score 3):

```
'Player 1: +str(player1points)\n'
```

Is just a string, even though it contains something that may be Python code. Thankfully, Python won't magically evaluate that. That string will be passed **literally** to the function. Look at the syntax highlighting of the line above and compare it to this, which actually adds `player1points` to the string `Player 1:`:

```
'Player 1: '+str(player1points)+'\n'
```

You see, have to put the `str` call and `+` outside of the string literal so they mean anything to Python. (And while you're at it, you might want to switch to string formatting, i.e. `"Player 1: %d" % player1points` or `"Player 1: {}".format(player1points)`.)

The error message specifically is caused by this line:

```
points = re.search(r'\d+$', player_report).group()
```

Since there's nothing number-like in the line (only `"+str(player1points)"`), `re.search` wil return `None` instead of a match objects - and `None` obviously doesn't know anything about groups.

Comment: You are amazing!  That was indeed the problem.  My professor hasn't taught us about the format that you've suggested since this is a Year 1 computer science, but it is nice to know that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use [formatting strings](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html) instead of the + operator for concatenation in python.  I'm also not sure why you want to pass a string for which you already have the point value to a function that extracts the point value?

You could try something like this (although I'm not sure why what you have would be failing..)

```
mystr = "Player 1: %d" % player1points
print points(mystr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[,reverse]]])
>
> Return a new sorted list
>   from the items in iterable.

Your code is a paddling pool. But it seems that the data you have to treat is a string. So I do:

```
ch = '''\
Player 1: 3

Player 2: 4

Player 3: 3

Player 4: 5
'''
print ch

import re

pat = re.compile('(Player (\d+): (\d+))')

print '------------'
print '\n'.join(x[2] for x in
                sorted((-int(points),number,report)
                       for (report, number, points)
                       in pat.findall(ch)))
```

result

```
Player 1: 3

Player 2: 4

Player 3: 3

Player 4: 5

------------
Player 4: 5
Player 2: 4
Player 1: 3
Player 3: 3
```

If the input data isn't a string, explain what it is and I will modify the code.